# continuation is not coming in autoscroll

Tags: javascript, css, html

Please check the website http://psnexim.com/.
1. There is the products section. The images are continuing. It is coming back to the original position. I have given width of the container to be 1650px. I am not good in JS. SO anyone can HELP. Here is the JS code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var width = -150;
        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            $(".scroll-container").css({'left':width+'px','transition' : 'all ease 1s'});
            if(width == -1650) {
                width = 150;
            }
            width -= 150;

        },2000);
    });
    </script>
```

2. There is a video in the main page. I have put it by using the tag . How to decrease the height of that video without changing the width? Here is the code for video:

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code..

```
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    video.setAttribute('height', '300');
    video.setAttribute('width ', '700');
```

Comment: try this   var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
  video.height = 300;
   video.width = 700;

Comment: For your understanding refer Responsive Embed from Bootstrap.visit w3school.com